# Regex check dob with optional for gender

Tags: javascript, regex

`((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-[12]\d{3})`

Using the above I check for dob eg: 02-03-1980

I'd like to check for an optional gender eg: `02-03-1980 m` or `02-03-1980 f` but would also like to accept the dob without gender too.

Comment: /((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-[12]\d{3})( [mf])?/

Comment: If you don't need the capturing groups for further processing, you could make them non capturing as well `\b(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])-[12]\d{3}(?: [mf])?\b` https://regex101.com/r/dtjcKj/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-[12]\d{3}(?:\s[mf])?)
```

https://regex101.com/r/c1oRdB/1